# How to remove the extra space after table heading, in datatables which has scrollbar and filter?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, datatables

[image]

I'm using datatables.net library.  There is a gap between table header and the table body, if I add scrollbar. Is there any way to remove it?  Also, is there a way to move the searchbox to the left, and remove the text "Search:", and instead add it as a place holder within the textbox?

Comment: Just curious, is there anything wrong with the question? why is it being downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that library but I do know that one can easily modify CSS to achieve the desired layout.
Please check their documentation about styling http://datatables.net/styling/