# how to remove padding in datatable column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Is there any way of setting the datatable options to reduce the column padding? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32955610/r-shiny-dtrenderdatatable-column-width?noredirect=1&lq=1) suggested using `autoWidth=TRUE` along with `scrollX=TRUE`, but it doesn't work in my code.

As you can see in the image below there is a big gap between columns forcing the user to scroll across, which I'd prefer to avoid if possible. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912520/removing-extra-padding-in-datatables-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816649/how-to-remove-the-extra-space-after-table-heading-in-datatables-which-has-scrol) one have the same problem in java

[image]

Here's the code for rendering the datatable.

```
output$book_table <-  DT::renderDT(RVTables$book %>% 
                                     filter(deal==as.numeric(input$deal_choice)),
                                   selection = list(mode="single",selected=row_edited),
                                   editable = TRUE,
                                   rownames = FALSE,
                                   options=list(
                                     autoWidth=TRUE,
                                     scrollX = TRUE,
                                     ordering=FALSE,
                                     pageLength=12,
                                     scrollY = TRUE,
                                     bLengthChange= FALSE,
                                     searching=FALSE
                                   )
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 'strategy' col width is the same as column name length so if you want it to be smaller, make column name with wrapped text or smaller.

Comment: yes I could do that, but is there no easy way to reduce the gap between column headings? there's a lot of padding after the name

Comment: As far as I know, no. Length of the column is no less than length of column name.

Comment: that's ok, but there seems to be padding btw column headings, look at the gap btw the number columns, and columns 2 and 3

Answer (score 8):

After some google searching I found the line of code `class="compact cell-border",` which reduces the padding around column headers. Here is my code to render the table in case it helps anyone else.

```
output$book_table <- DT::renderDataTable({    
    DT::datatable(
      deal_reactive(),
      editable = TRUE,
      rownames = FALSE,
      class="compact cell-border",
      selection = list(mode = "single", 
                       target = "row", 
                       selected = previous_row),
      options = list(
        dom="t",
        autoWidth=TRUE,
        scrollX = TRUE,
        ordering=FALSE,
        pageLength = 28, 
        bLengthChange= FALSE,
        displayStart = previous_page,
        searching=FALSE
        )
      )
  })
```